# Using VIEW to fill missing data from a MATERIALIZED VIEW for append-only data?

Tags: postgresql, materialized-views, postgresql-14

I want to create a `MATERIALIZED VIEW` called `ohlc` that calculates the [OHLC](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/o/ohlcchart.asp) values of a stock's price. Stock prices are stored in an append-only `price` table.

The pricing data is updated regularly but `ohlc` is only refreshed once per hour. This got me thinking... Is it possible to bridge the gap by layering a `VIEW` on top of the `MATERIALIZED VIEW`?

Meaning, is it possible to define a `VIEW` that would return values from the `ohlc` table if they exists; and otherwise calculate the values on the fly? This means that the majority of rows would come from the cache, and only the most recent data would have to get calculated on the fly.

Is such a thing possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to achieve this is by constructing your `VIEW` as a `UNION ALL` between 1) the `ohlc` materialized view and 2) the query you use to build `ohlc`, but filtered by timestamps greater than the max timestamp recorded in `ohlc`.  This is not the most elegant solution, but I believe it is the simplest.

Comment: Is there a way to join the two tables on a common unique key, and instruct the query to always return the left row if it exists; otherwise, return the right row?

Comment: I think you're referring to a `RIGHT JOIN` -- but that will produce two columns.  From there, you can use `COALESCE` to select the Left if populated, and use Right if Left is null

Comment: Right, so the question becomes: will the optimizer be smart enough to skip the calculation if the MATERIALIZED VIEW's row is non-null. I guess I'll test that at some point.